# How to use $\delta$ to express $\int_{0}^{t}\cos[m(x-\beta)]\cos xdx$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have done integration by parts twice, and it comes to:
\begin{align}
I(t)&=\int_{0}^{t}\cos[m(x-\beta)]\cos x dx\\&=\left[\cos[m(x-\beta)]\sin x\right]_0^t+m\int_{0}^{t}\sin[m(x-\beta)]\sin x dx\\
&=\cos[m(t-\beta)]\sin t-m\left\{\sin[m(x-\beta)]\cos x\right\}_0^t+m^2I(t)\\
&=\cos[m(t-\beta)]\sin t-m\sin[m(t-\beta)]\cos t-m\sin(m\beta)+m^2I(t)
\end{align}
So $$\lim_{t\to2\pi}I(t)=\lim_{t\to2\pi}\frac{\cos[m(t-\beta)]\sin t-m\sin[m(t-\beta)]\cos t-m\sin(m\beta)}{1-m^2}\to\delta_{m1}\pi\cos(m\beta)$$
The difficulty is how to express the whole thing into the last step.

Note here $m$ is not necessarily restricted to be integer.

**EDIT**: If the trigonometric formula applied, it seems much messier
\begin{align}
I(t)&=\frac{\sin((m+1)x-m\beta)|_0^t}{2(m+1)}+\frac{\sin((m-1)x-m\beta)|_0^t}{2(m-1)}\\&=\frac{\sin((m+1)t-m\beta)+\sin(m\beta)}{2(m+1)}+\frac{\sin((m-1)t-m\beta)+\sin(m\beta)}{2(m-1)}\\
&=\frac{(m-1)\sin((m+1)t-m\beta)+(m+1)\sin((m-1)t-m\beta)+2m\sin(m\beta)}{2(m^2-1)}
\end{align}

Comment: Why these complicated computations ? Just transform the integrand by using $\cos a \cos b=\frac12(\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b))$...

Comment: Yes, I have tried but it is another form even messier as shown in edit.